# KnockoutJs Single page application with pagerJs - You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, single-page-application, pagerjs

Hi I have a small problem for a single page application using knockout and pagerjs.

In my index.html I have

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 30px;" id="container">
  <span id="span" onclick = 'clickme(this)'>
    I am span
  </span>
  <div data-bind="page: {id: 'start' , title : 'First Page'}">
    you are currently viewing the content of first page. 
    <br />
    <a  href="#!/start/deep">
      first child
    </a>
    <br />
    <a  href="#!/start/second">
      second child
    </a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div data-bind="page: {id: 'deep', title : 'Second Page',role: 'start', source: 'views/test1.html'}">
      you are currently viewing the content of first page inside First Page.
      <br />
      <a data-bind="page-href :'../second'" >
        Second Child
      </a>
    </div>

    <div data-bind="page: {id: 'second', title : 'Second Page', source: 'views/test.html'}">
      you are currently viewing the content of second page inside Second Page.
      <br />
      <a data-bind="page-href :'../deep'" >
        First Child
      </a>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a  href="#!/structure">
      Go to Structure
    </a>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="page: {id: 'structure', title : 'Second Page'}">
    you are currently viewing the content of second page.
    <br />
    <a  href="#!/start">
      Go to Start
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My javascript on the index page looks like this

```
function PagerViewModel(){
        var self    =   this;
    }

    $(function () {
        pager.Href.hash = '#!/';
        pager.extendWithPage(PagerViewModel.prototype);
        ko.applyBindings(new PagerViewModel(), document.getElementById("container"));
        pager.start();
    });
```

In the test.html file i have

```
<div id="two">
......
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
........
var viewModel = new PointPageModel([
    { name: "page1"},
    { name: "page2"},
    { name: "page3"},
    { name: "page"}
]);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("two"));
</script>
```

I still receive Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element. 
Didn't I bind to different elements ? Any advise will be appreciated.

Best regards,
Gavril

Comment: is your div "two" included in the container div on the test.html page?

Comment: Indeed, your div 'two' is probably inside the container. When you apply bindings, you apply them to the target element and ALL ITS CHILDREN. Since 'two' is a child of container, you end up applying bindings to that element twice. Or at least, that might be the issue :)

Comment: two is a children of the page container. I need to bind once for the pagerjs to work and once for the view model for that page. Any way of doing this ? It would be great if you can point me to a single page application that uses pagerjs and loads pages that have their own view model to bind

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use custom binding to stop binding children of an element.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
        init: function () {
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };
```

Then you can wrap your "two" element in another div and use it like this:

```
<div data-bind="stopBinding: true">
    <div id="two">
    ......
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want pager to receive its own viewmodel rather than setting one up over the whole page, but I think what you want is a viewmodel for each sub page, in which case you probably are after:

```
data-bind="page: {id: 'second', title : 'Second Page', source: 'views/test.html', withOnShow: viewModel()}"
```

which will give you a viewmodel for this page after it has been opened. (Code not tested, you may need to move the viewModel declaration around a bit).

From the Pager.js reference page: http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/start/config

> withOnShow : Function(Function(Object), Page)
>   This member makes it possible to lazy-bind a view-model once the page is first displayed. withOnShow takes a method that should take 2 arguments: a callback (that should be feeded the view-model) and the current Page-object.
>
> This property is very useful when you want to split up your view-model for your single page application into multiple smaller view-models that can still communicate with each other. You might feed a page a view-model for a certain item.
>
> If you set sourceCache: true the view-model will not reload every time you revisit the page.

```
<div data-bind="page: {id: '?', withOnShow: Cool.loadUser}">
    <h1 data-bind="text: userName"></h1>
</div>
Cool.loadUser = function(callback, page) {
    $.get('service/users/' + page.currentId, function(data) {
        callback(ko.mapping.fromJSON(data));
    });
};
```